# Date_diff if value is same

Tags: php, date

I am facing with a problem.
When  `$start`  and  `$end`  have the same value, the Days in  `$intervalo->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s")`  will return 0.

How can I change this, that if same value (date) the Days = 1.

Thanks for your help!!!

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
$start='2021-09-17';
$end='2021-09-17';
$intervalo = date_diff(date_create($start), date_create($end));

echo $intervalo->format("Years:%Y,Months:%M,Days:%d,Hours:%H,Minutes:%i,Seconds:%s");
```

Comment: It returns 0 when you want it to return 1. A dirty way would be something like `if x=0 then x=1`

Comment: Hello @B001ᛦ! Thanks for your help, but this does not work every time, because of some other part of my code. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it and keeping with the way you're formatting you can simply do:

```
...
$intervalo->d = $intervalo->days === 0 ? 1 : $intervalo->d;
echo $intervalo->format(...
```

Check the [result type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) of `array_diff` to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!